# Broadcasting to subnet address using pyzmq

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

I am trying to use broadcasting packets to subnet address, I successfully tried to do that using socket's broadcast option, But I recently started learning ZeroMQ so I would like to use it to broadcast the packets to the subnet. I used `zmq.PUB`, `zmq.SUB` but at the subscriber side, the packets are undelivered because I use subnet address. If I use IP address of the machine then it works, but that's not what I want.

Is there any option for broadcasting using ZMQ?

---

Here is the code I tried so far:

## Publisher:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://192.X.X.255:9999")  # Note.

while True:
    socket.send_string('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

## Subscriber:

```
context = zmq.Context()
sub=context.socket(zmq.SUB)  # Note.
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")  # Note.
sub.connect('tcp://192.x.x.255:9999') -> publishing only to subnet

while True:
    print(sub.recv())
```

---

We can do the broadcasting of packets using a regular socket, for example, using:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
```

But I want to replace this in a way I do it with ZMQ. Does the ZMQ really have a broadcast discovery in a different way or we should use the same code above as we do for regular broadcasting?

Comment: I don't know about "subnet address" meaning, but with using the `.bind("tcp://*:1234")` in publisher side, each subscriber could connect on it and get the message over ZMQ with `.connect("tcp://publisher-ip:1234")`, Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, Subnet address is the ip address and the broadcast address mix, for example only the ppl connect to the router wifi gets the message which we send. The address will look like 192.167.1.255, You can see in your ifconfig. So this will avoid sending message to all.(255.255.255.255) @Benyamin jafari . My publisher and subscriber both will use same subnet address. One to publish and other one to subscriber.

Comment: Hi, I think still do not understand what you mean. So I will take an example as an answer, if it wouldn't help you, I'll remove it.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari The answer you posted might help only for the publisher who wants to publish to the whole network. "*" this means i think 255.255.255.255 address. Everyone can listen to the publisher, I want it to be private thats why i use subnet address. By the way if you could help, Apart from pub-sub or whatever messaging pattern, i really need to find a zmq way for broadcasting udp packet.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have three *Machines (M1, M2, M3)* with three different IP addresses with the same subnet and a defined port. We want to publish a message (from *M1*) to each subscribers (*M1, M2*), therefore we would have the following code snippet:

### Publisher (Machine1):

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:9999")  # Note.

while True:
    socket.send_string('hello-all')
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

### Subscriber (Machine2):

```
context = zmq.Context()
sub=context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
sub.connect('tcp://Machine1_IP:9999')  # Note

while True:
    print(sub.recv())
```

---

### Subscriber (Machine3):

```
context = zmq.Context()
sub=context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"")
sub.connect('tcp://Machine1_IP:9999')  # Note

while True:
    print(sub.recv())
```

Comment: Perfect, saved me hours of digging.